# download kernel source code : error : Not enough diskspace (900MB) on /root

Tags: sd-card, kernel

I need to download the source code of my current kernel with `rpi-source` command

I receive an error  `Not enough diskspace (900MB) on /root`

I have an 8GB SD card. ubuntu shows me two partitions one boot of 58MB and another 2.9GB volume.

so where are the 5GB remaining space?????

Comment: What distro are you running Raspbian, Arch or smething else. If you are running Raspbian you can run sudo raspi-config the script has an option to resize the partition to utilize the remaining free space on the SD card.

Comment: thanks a lot, it works, im running Raspbian and file system was re-sized to the whole  space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as answered in the first comment, run `sudo raspi-config` and select the first option `expend Filesystem`. this will use the whole SD card size.